# How do I store unsigned integers in Cassandra?

Tags: c#, .net, cassandra, data-modeling

I am storing some data in Cassandra via the Datastax driver, and I have the need to store unsigned 16-bit and 32-bit integers. For unsigned 16-bit integers, I can easily store them as signed 32-bit integers and cast them as needed. For unsigned 64-bit integers, however, I am at a loss. I can store them as strings and parse them, or I can store them as byte arrays. I could store them as 64-bit signed integers and do the bit manipulation required to convert from and to 64-bit unsigned integers.

What is the recommended way?

Comment: How about `varint` and `decimal`? Are those not available from .net?

Comment: Pretty crazy that cassandra doesnt support uint. I guess it shows how infrequently uint is used in real world situations or there would be enough pressure on them to support it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use Cassandra's `varint`, represented in the C# Driver as [BigInteger](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.numerics.biginteger(v=vs.110).aspx).

You can do [explicit conversions](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd268211(v=vs.110).aspx) from `BigInteger` to `ushort`and `ulong`.

Comment: That's probably the best way, but `BigInteger` has performance implications relative to `ulong` :(

Comment: You can use `long` and then do `unchecked { ulong value = (ulong) longValue; }`