# What is the difference between INT and VARINT in Cassandra Datatypes?

Tags: types, cassandra

Can someone please explain the difference between INT and VARINT data types in Cassandra. When should I use VARINT and what are its advantages ?

Answer (score 5):

As mentioned in the answer

- [How do I store unsigned integers in Cassandra?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29237891/how-do-i-store-unsigned-integers-in-cassandra#29252394)

and described in the [Cassandra documentation](https://docs.datastax.com/en/cql/3.3/cql/cql_reference/cql_data_types_c.html), `int` is a 32-bit integer whereas `varint` is an arbitrary-precision integer implemented by [java.math.BigInteger](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/math/BigInteger.html).  As such `int` will be smaller and faster compared to `varint` but limited in its range.

[java.math.BigInteger](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/math/BigInteger.html) has been discussed previously in these stack overflow questions:

- [What are the limits of BigDecimal and BigInteger?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17945985/what-are-the-limits-of-bigdecimal-and-biginteger#17946017)
- [What does BigInteger having no limit mean?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12088436/what-does-biginteger-having-no-limit-mean)

Answer (score -3):

int is final.... varint is not. Like static in C/C++/java